# Eclipse update does not go away

Tags: eclipse, updates

I am using Eclipse Mars.2 Release 4.5.2. 
When I check for updates Eclipse shows the following item:

> **Object Teams Patch for JDT/Core**
>
> This feature is NOT a regular update of the JDT, but REPLACES the org.exlipse.jdt.core plugin by the corresponding version for Object Teams.
>   This change makes the JDT Core capable to handle OT/J code.

When I click on finish the window goes away and Eclipse says that I need to restart for the changes to take effect. When I restart and check for updates the update is still there and not installed.

Is there a way to get rid of this update?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this feature installed? If yes and if you don't use it, I suggest you simply go an remove it (`Help > About Eclipse... > Installation Details > Installed Software`, you'll see an `Uninstall` button).

If this persists, it could be a small issue in the main Eclipse update-site, so you should report it to http://bugs.eclipse.org .